# What does the following do?

Tags: perl

could someone tell me what this does?

```
my ($pkg, @elements) = @_;
my $me = "${pkg}::new()";
```

Comment: Considering You just asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188876/could-someone-tell-me-what-this-means-in-perl/7188992) three minutes ago which was also related to Perl, I suspect this is homework.

Comment: Have you been to [learn.perl.org?](http://learn.perl.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my ($pkg, @elements) = @_;
```

Is commonly seen here:

```
sub perl_func () {
  my ($pkg, @elements) = @_;   
}
```

It's equivalent to the following in PHP:

```
list ($pkg, $elements) = $an_array;
```

In the above context it is Perl's weird way of implementing function parameters, do imagine it looks like this:

```
sub perl_func ($pkg, @elements) {
}
```

Finally this:

```
my $me = "${pkg}::new()";
```

Is just a string, consider:

```
my $pkg = "rhubarb";
```

Then, `$me = "rhubarb::new()"`

Comment: perfect explaination, thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: There's nothing weird about perl's implementation of subroutine parameters.

Comment: `sub perl_func ($pkg, @elements) { ... }` is just plain wrong. This ain't Java

Comment: @TLP to newcomers, everything about Perl is weird  :-)

Comment: @Zaid I think that was meant to be pseudo-code. Steve: To newcomers, every language is weird. =P